# Getting incorrect value form firebase in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is my code

```
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("chats").document(userDefaults.string(forKey: "currentGroup")!).collection("messages").document("variable").addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print("Error fetching document")
            }
            else{
                let documentData = snapshot!.data()
                print(documentData!["numOfMessages"])
                self.numOfMessages = documentData!["numOfMessages"] as! Int
                print(self.numOfMessages)
                //Get texts and display them
                db.collection("chats").document(self.userDefaults.string(forKey: "currentGroup")!).collection("messages").document("\(self.numOfMessages)").getDocument { (document, err) in
                    let newMessageData = document!.data()
                    let newMessage = newMessageData!["message"] as! String
                    let newAuthor = newMessageData!["author"] as! String
                    let authorLabel = UILabel()
                    authorLabel.text = newAuthor
                    self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(authorLabel)
                    let label = UILabel()
                    label.text = newMessage
                    self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
                }
            }
        }
```

This line `self.numOfMessages = documentData!["numOfMessages"] as! Int` has an error of

> Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x1ed6ed450) to 'NSNumber' (0x1ed6f98c8).

This is every since I deleted the collection `messages` and replaced it with one of the exact same name

The value that `documentData!["numOfMessages"]` returns is `Optional(1)` even though in firebase the value is 2.

This is how the Firestore looks:

[image]

Comment: The error clearly says that the value for key `numOfMessages` is `String` not `Int`.

Comment: Yes, I understand that but the value I am getting from firebase is an Int though which is causing my confusion as it clearly says in the question

Comment: *...but the value I am getting from firebase is an Int*  –  Sorry, the error states you don't.

Comment: Thats the whole reason I am asking the question though... because the value I am trying to get is an integer and firebase recognises it as that, but when I try to get it it is a string and if you read the question again it is even giving the wrong number

Answer (score 1):

Either you are listening to the wrong document (perhaps because of an incorrect user default) or you are unwrapping the value incorrectly. To debug this, try the following and see what the problem actually is. The following is a more idiomatic way of handling documents.

```
if let currentGroup = userDefaults.string(forKey: "currentGroup") {
    print(currentGroup) // this could be your problem
    
    Firestore.firestore().collection("chats").document(currentGroup).collection("messages").document("variable").addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
        if let snapshot = snapshot {
            if let numOfMessages = snapshot.get("numOfMessages") as? Int {
                print(numOfMessages)
            } else {
                print("field error")
            }
        } else if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
} else {
    print("no current group")
}
```